# To be (of) an ethnicity/nationality/race

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

Are these sentences interchangeable?

- I wouldn't hate someone because they are a particular ethnicity/nationality/race
- I wouldn't hate someone because they are of a particular ethnicity/nationality/race

I know in questions, we can say, "What ethnicity/nationality/race are you" instead of "What ethnicity/nationality/race are you of." I think it might be wrong to omit "of" in sentences other than questions.

Comment: to be a nationality and to belong to an ethnic group. Forget race.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing two sentences because the context of the sentences makes them equivalent. Replacing "of" with "a part of" brings some clarity.

*"What race are you?" vs "What race are you a part of?"*

and

*"I wouldn't hate someone because they are a particular race" vs "I wouldn't hate someone because they are a part of a particular race"*

So it's the difference between *being* and *belonging*. When talking about ethnicity/nationality/race you can both *be* and *belong* to an ethnicity/nationality/race, which is why the sentences are equivalent. But if you were to reword it to use a social club or an innate feature like age, you will see that in a different context where *being* and *belonging* are not equivalent, the sentences are not equivalent and some of them don't make sense.

*"What club are you?" (being - doesn't make sense) vs "What club are you a part of?" (belonging)*

and

*"I wouldn't hate someone because they are a particular age" (being) vs "I wouldn't hate someone because they are a part of a particular age" (belonging - doesn't make sense)*

So it doesn't matter whether it's a statement or a question, just what the context is. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks. So you say the sentences I gave are interchangeable. Do you think “What ethnicity/nationality/race are you of” is correct too? Might it be kind of stilted?